# image_picker plugin for flutter shows unusual warning

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am using the following code to pick an image with maxHeight/width to save space.

```
    void openGallery()async {
    var gallery = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: maxImageSize,
      maxWidth: maxImageSize,
    );
    if (gallery!=null) {
      var bytes = await gallery.readAsBytes();
      if (DEBUG) print('Image bytes: ${bytes.length / 1024} KB');
      if (DEBUG) print('Image path: ${gallery.path}');
      setState(() {
        List<int> imageBytes = gallery.readAsBytesSync();
        _imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);
        // decoded = base64Decode(_imageB64);
        if (DEBUG) print('Base64 String length: ${_imageB64.length / 1024} KB');
      });
    }
  }
```

I am getting this following warning in my console:

```
image_picker: compressing is not supported for type (null). Returning the image with original quality
flutter: Image bytes: 153.583984375 KB
flutter: Image path: ...myimagpath.jpg
flutter: Base64 String length: 204.78125 KB
```

1) On one side I can see that my image is reduced in size as it is only 200kB but on the other hand the first line is confusing me.

2) Also, I was under the impression that BASE64 encoded images get smaller in size, As I want to save them to Firebase, will there be a problem saving them as just 'bytes' (as it is 153kb)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's working fine with my code.

```
var selectedProfileImage;


Future _getImage(bool fromCamera) async {
  File image;
  if (fromCamera) {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 150.0, maxHeight: 150.0);
  } else {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 150.0, maxHeight: 150.0);
  }
  if (image != null) {
    // Initiate the ProgessBar
    selectedProfileImage = image;

  }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference in your code, I am doing the same thing already